# Как удалить все "&" со строки?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

С помощью `re = /\&*/g;` не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант #1 с реугляркой:**

```js
var str = 'Текст& с символом & и еще нескол&ьким&и так&ими сим&волами';
str = str.replace(/&/g,'');
console.log(str);
```

**Вариант #2 на `.split()` и `.join()`:**

```js
var str = 'Текст& с символом & и еще нескол&ьким&и так&ими сим&волами';
str = str.split('&').join('');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: регулярки рулят

Answer (score 7):

Можно без регулярки

```
$str = 'Текст и && &амперсанд';

echo str_replace('&', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Так все работает

```
$string = 'Текст& с символом & и еще нескол&ьким&и так&ими сим&волами';
$pattern = '/\&*/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```